# Can not open bundle file in test case

Tags: unit-testing, file, path, resources, bundle

I have a test case that reads a .stringsdict file.

import XCTest

@testable import CheminDeLaVieSwift

class TestChemin: XCTestCase {

```
func testCheminParDefault0() {
    ...
}
```

}

This test function creates an instance of an object which contains the following line of code:

```
    path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fichier, ofType: extensionFichier)!
```

When running the application, this line works ok.  But in the test function, it always returns nil.

In the projects configuration, for the test target, I've added the .stringsdict file in the "Copy bundle Resources" section.  The bundle path still returns nil.

Comment: By the way, I am using XCode 11 with SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

In the project settings, I selected the test target, under General, in the 'Host Application' field, I had changed the value to none.  Now I set it back to my application name.